# Android studio emulator launch in tool feature is not working

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have an Android Studio ver 4.2.0 .
I'm using Flutter and Dart.

The problem is that I'm trying to launch the emulator in the same Android Studio window( launch in tool feature) I have the launch in tool option checked in from the settings but it's not working, the emulator still launch in a separate window, I have checked it in and out then relaunched the android studio software but nothing changed the emulator still launched in a separate window, does this feature not work with Flutter and Dart?

[emulator photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSCWf.jpg)

[sdk photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIJC5.jpg)